# How do I pass an integer argument to a shell script which then passes it to a program?

Tags: c++, bash, shell, g++, command-line-arguments

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
set n = $argv[1]
g++ main.cpp
./a.out n
```

I am trying to call it in the shell like this:

```
myscript 3
```

The output is different from doing the following

```
./a.out 3
```

But I want it to be the same. How is it done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be using a mixture of different shell syntaxes.

- 'set' does not set ordinary variables. Just use `n=value`
- Use $1 for argv[1]
- Expand variables by putting a $ in front, as in the last line below

This does what I think you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=$1
g++ main.cpp
./a.out $n
```

You can also pass all supplied arguments through using $@, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ main.cpp
./a.out $@
```